# Necessidade de testar a heterocedasticidade antes de usar o teste Kruskal-Wallis

Tags: comparação, anova

A Minha pergunta é se devo ou não testar a heterodasticidade antes de usar o teste de Kruskal-Wallis.

O que eu entendo é que se eu quiser comparar medianas/média, então tenho que verificar a heterocedasticidade, mas se meu objetivo é usar o teste para verificar se uma amostra é estocasticamente diferente do que a outra, não tenho necessariamente que verificar suposições .

No artigo de Kruskal e Wallis (Use of Ranks in One-Criterion Variance Analysis), no final da página 17/40 ou numerado como 598 que:

**4.2. Comparison of Means when Variability Differs Rigorously interpreted, all we can conclude from a significant value of H is that the populations differ, not necessarily that the means differ.**

ou entre outros

[**If you wish to compare medians or means, then the Kruskal-Wallis test also assumes that observations in each group are identically and independently distributed apart from location. If you can accept inference in terms of dominance of one distribution over another, then there are indeed no distributional assumptions.**](https://influentialpoints.com/Training/Kruskal-Wallis_ANOVA_use_and_misuse.htm)

Já encontrei professores concordando e discordando neste assunto. Agradeço sua orientação.

Comment: maiores chances de sua pergunta ser respondida no Cross-Validation: https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Lucas Obrigado